# Can I use PHP inside CSS pseudo class

Tags: css, wordpress

I have this code

```
a:after{
content url:(/path to my image/my_image.png)
  ......
}
```

and it works fine. But I am now migrating my site to WordPress. I can't use the WordPress function `get_theme_file_uri();` to get my image path Or is there another alternative.

Comment: how is this a php question? There's only CSS here.

Comment: You need to add your PHP code when you tag PHP!

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're running your CSS documents through a PHP `eval()` function (which you shouldn't do by most standards) there isn't a good way to execture PHP inside of CSS. The best way to solve your issue is linking directly to the image.

Assuming your directory structure is something like:

```
[..]
    [wp-admin]
    [wp-content]
        [uploads]
            [images]
               --my-image.jpg--
    [wp-includes]
    --other files--
```

You could use it by simply using a relative path to the file, like:

```
a::after {
    content: url(/wp-content/uploads/images/my-image.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS urls are relative to the CSS file.

if you have structure like

```
..
images
    my_image.png
index.php
style.css
```

you can use a relative URL like:

```
a:after{
    content url:(images/my_image.png)
}
```